# Como passar uma lista <GridTile> para o StaggeredGridView?

Tags: flutter

Eu estou retornando uma lista de imagens para colocar em um StaggeredGridView. O problema é que eu não estou conseguindo encontrar uma forma de passar a lista dentro do NetworkImage(). Como eu poderia fazer isso?

```
List<GridTile> gridTilesList = [];
      postsList.forEach((eachPost) {
        gridTilesList.add(GridTile(child: PostTile(eachPost)));
      });
      return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        itemCount: countPost, //staticData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
              child: InkWell(
                  child: Hero(
                    tag: index,
                    child: new Image(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      image: NetworkImage(gridTilesList[index]
                          .toString()),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    //
                  }));
        },
        staggeredTileBuilder: (index) =>
            StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 3),
        mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
      );
```

Está aparecendo este erro:

**══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE** ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///GridTile

**Obs:** Com o GridView está funcionando normalmente:

```
List<GridTile> gridTilesList = [];
      postsList.forEach((eachPost) {
        gridTilesList.add(GridTile(child: PostTile(eachPost)));
      });
      return GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        crossAxisSpacing: 1.5,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: gridTilesList,
      );
```

Comment: Sua variável ```gridTilesList``` é uma lista de GridTiles. O que o construtor do NetworkImage precisa é uma string que diz um caminho da imagem. Por exemplo, "site.com/abc.jpg". A partir do momento que você coloca uma string que não representa isso, ele não consegue achar uma imagem. Não entendi *qual* imagem você quer colocar no NetworkImage.

Comment: Entendi, então talvez não seja o NetworkImage que eu devo usar. A lista de GridTiles está retornando cada imagem que está no meu storage, a ideia é fazer no StaggeredGridView a mesma coisa que eu fiz no GridView.